# Adding content to an Outlook email body via an Office Add-In

Tags: outlook, ms-office

I've created an Office add-in and want to add some html content to the body of the email. This works but the content get somewhat transformed so my css is not working. For some reason the add "x_" as prefix to the attributes (see image)

[image: part of rendered hmtl in image body]

I'm using the Office.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync method to add the html.

You can find the code on GitHub: https://github.com/genevangampelaere/OutlookTrelloAddIn

Comment: The answer solves a problem, but doesn't answer as to why Outlook is inserting "x_" on my attributes. If I insert into the email body the HTML <div id="my_id" class="my_class">...</div> Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync, and later when I get the email body using Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync - the attributes on my div now have "x_", (i.e.  <div id="x_my_id" class="x_my_class">...</div> ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's adding the x_ prefix, but the main problem is that you are setting css styles, not classes, and that should be in a `style` attribute not a `class` attribute.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync("<div style=\"border-left-width: 2px;border-left-color: #0067A3;border-left-style: solid;padding-left: 10px;\"><h2>" + card.name + "</h2><div>" + card.desc + "</div></div>", { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
```

Comment: OMG! What a stupid error. This is my fault. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from Microsoft in their add-in documentation (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Body).

"When working with HTML-formatted bodies, it is important to note that the Body.getAsync and Body.setAsync methods are not idempotent. The value returned from the getAsync method will not necessarily be exactly the same as the value that was passed in the setAsync method previously. The client may modify the value passed to setAsync in order to make it render efficiently with its rendering engine."

Comment: Another discussion on this is found at https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/43943713/bodysetasync+munges+value+returned+from+bodygetasync.